Seaborn boxplot add annotation labels for max values
I would like to show some values in a Seaborn box plot such as Total# observations, Mean, Mix/Max value for each box plot series. Is there a way to show these in the plot?
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.set_theme(style="ticks")

# Initialize the figure with a logarithmic x axis
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7, 6))
ax.set_xscale("log")

# Load the example planets dataset
planets = sns.load_dataset("planets")

# Plot the orbital period with horizontal boxes
sns.boxplot(
    planets, x="distance", y="method", hue="method",
    whis=[0, 100], width=.6, palette="vlag"
)

# Add in points to show each observation
sns.stripplot(planets, x="distance", y="method", size=4, color=".3")

# Tweak the visual presentation
ax.xaxis.grid(True)
ax.set(ylabel="")
sns.despine(trim=True, left=True)

Example output:


Display as you wish, but an easy way to get statistics is: x="distance"; y="method"; stats = planets.groupby(y)[x].describe(), then you can read like: stats.loc["Imaging", "mean"].

Just use matplotlib text function with the "data coordinates" for x and y:
mytext = 'Total: XX \n Mean: YY \n Min Value: AA \n Max Value: BB'
ax.text(x=15000, y='Radial Velocity', 
        s=mytext, style='italic', 
        color='white', bbox = {'facecolor': 'black'}, 
        fontsize=8, verticalalignment='center')
plt.show()



I made it a function:
def add_bplot_annotations(df, x, y, ax):
    stats = df.groupby(y)[x].describe()
    ticklabels = ax.get_yticklabels()
    transform = ax.get_yaxis_transform()

    for t in ticklabels:
        lbl = t.get_text()

        total = int(stats.loc[lbl, "count"])
        mean = stats.loc[lbl, "mean"]
        min_value = stats.loc[lbl, "min"]
        max_value = stats.loc[lbl, "max"]

        stats_str = f"Total: {total}\nMean: {mean:.2f}\nMin Value: {min_value:.2f}\nMax Value: {max_value:.2f}"
        ax.text(
            x=1,
            y=lbl,
            s=stats_str,
            style="italic",
            color="white",
            bbox={"facecolor": "black"},
            fontsize=8,
            verticalalignment="center",
            transform=transform,
        )

Result:

Full code:
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.set_theme(style="ticks")

# Initialize the figure with a logarithmic x axis
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 7))
ax.set_xscale("log")

# Load the example planets dataset
planets = sns.load_dataset("planets")
x = "distance"
y = "method"

# Plot the orbital period with horizontal boxes
sns.boxplot(planets, x=x, y=y, hue="method", whis=[0, 100], width=0.6, palette="vlag")

# Add in points to show each observation
sns.stripplot(planets, x=x, y=y, size=4, color=".3")

# Tweak the visual presentation
ax.xaxis.grid(True)
ax.set(ylabel="")
sns.despine(trim=True, left=True)

# Add annotations
add_bplot_annotations(planets, x, y, ax)


ax.figure.tight_layout()
plt.show()

